# Form submit event is not capturing OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, forms

I have a `button` and a `dropdownlst`

[image]

And I have this script :

```
$("form").submit(function (e)
    {
        $('#divOverlay').show();
        });
```

My Goal :

When a form submits , I need to show a "loading `div`" :

**Question :**

When I press the button it **does** show me the div  (the gray div which blinks for a second):

[image]

But when I change index on the dropdownlist  :

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="a"> a</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="b">b</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It does submit bUt I **dont** see the div :

[image]

Why does the `$("form").submit(function (e)` does not capture this postback which occurs after selected index change ? ?

NB :

Fiddler shows both events (pressing the button && changing index) as a `POST` command

**What is the structure of the file  ? ( psuedo) :**

```
<html  >
<head>
 ...     
</head>
<body>
    <div id='divOverlay'>  
       ...
    </div>

        <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="sssssss"/>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
            ...
        </asp:DropDownList>

        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
                {
                    $("form").submit(function (e)
                    {
                            $('#divOverlay').show();
                    });
                });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Can you show the difference between both requests which sent to the server ? [**Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2eWA.png)**.**

The right side is when index is changed and the left pane is for button press

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073384/jquery-form-submitfn-does-not-work-with-asp-net

Comment: @Johan Tried with both document.ready and without - and it still doesn't work

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application
Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ASP.NET's method: [ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registeronsubmitstatement.aspx), that lets you run a JavaScript statement each time the HtmlForm is submitted

```
ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "divOverlayShow", "$('#divOverlay').show();");
```

Comment: This is working. thank you !I will investigate what JS it generates behind.

Comment: Strange , but `$("form").attr('onsubmit',   'alert(1);');` does work. while attaching JS event handler is not working....

Answer (score 1):

I guess the autopostback behaviour is to submit the form through javascript and a call to `__doPostBack()`, which does not trigger the submit event.

You may try :

```
<asp:DropDownList onchange="$('#divOverlay').show();" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Comment: submit is a javascript method of the form object. It is also an event triggered when the form is submitted by the user. But it is not triggered when the form is submitted through code. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/645555/1236044

Answer (score 0):

not sure, sounds like the postback of the DDL and of the form r apart of different.

anyways i would advice u to simply solve by dropping the autopostback from the DDL and add a client-side onchange where there u can either show the grey div and then manually postback the server-side onselect like this:
http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/force-updatepanel-postback.html
or just $("form").submit()

Comment: The whole purpose is to add a script which will show a div for a **given site** which means - not to touch the html and solve it with pure JS. and your solution requires to change functionallity/code for every page

Comment: i think i missed something here Royi, ur doing anyways this $("form").submit(function (e)  {   $('#divOverlay').show();    });, why cant u just add there some line? sorry for the ignorance m8

Comment: this is done on a seperate JS file (js file) .p.s. i already found a solution. tomorrow ill update.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help but this worked for me. I can show the overlay div in both events.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (e) { 
                alert("Submit");
            });
            $("#dropdown").change(function (e) {
                alert("Hi");
            });
        });

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitbutton" Text="submit"/>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChange"/>
</asp:Content>
```